# Erro com ID AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Meu problema é deixar o primeiro campo do INSERT vazio,(se eu preencho o programa roda), no meu phpmyadmin o campo ID está AUTO_INCREMENT, porem sem modificar essa parte do code, ela parou.

Código:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES ('','$user','$sobrenome','$sexo','$nascimento','$senha','$email','$foto','$status')";

$busca = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

$afetado = mysqli_affected_rows($link);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem dois jeitos de fazer INSERT, o jeito que voce ta fazendo, e falar quais colunas voce quer inserir

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3,...columnN)  
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);
```

Mais infos: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm

Nao posso montar o SQL pra vc pq nao sei as colunas, mas é fácil ;)

Comment: $busca = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

Comment: Aqui está o erro, esta retornando falso.

Comment: @GabrielCordeiro vc trocou o codigo pra ser as colunas que vc quer inserir e os valores correspondentes? Nao entendi seu comentario.

Comment: ignore meu comentario kkk bom fiz o que você me recomendou e tambem precisava adicionar "null" no valor do ID. OBG

Comment: Nao tenho como testar agora, mas tente inserir "pulando" a coluna do ID tanto na lista de colunas quanto no VALUES, acho que deveria funcionar. Mas que bom que te ajudou ;)

Answer (score 3):

Quanto você estiver inserindo dados numa tabela que possua um ID com AUTO_INCREMENT, sem especificar as colunas que estará preenchendo (que é o caso do seu exemplo), você deve deixar o valor do ID com 'null'.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES (null,'$user','$sobrenome','$sexo','$nascimento','$senha','$email','$foto','$status')";
```

Outra maneira é declarando os campos onde os dados serão inseridos na tabela. Informando os campos da tabela antes do VALUES dentro de parenteses.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (user, senha, email) VALUES ('$user','$senha','$email')";
```

Comment: Era isso... Obg

Comment: De nada! Tmj ;)